# Python assignment command grammar

Tags: python, variable-assignment, grammar

I am reading the following python code snippet and there is something I don't understand. root is a self defined class which represents a tree node. Can anyone explain why the assignment command of root works in that way?

```
   while (p.val - root.val) * (q.val - root.val) > 0:
        root = [root.left, root.right][p.val > root.val]
```

Comment: `root` is assigned either the first or second element of the list based on the condition in the subscript.

Comment: The assignment isn't really relevant here. The code makes a list `[root.left, root.right]` and indexes it with a boolean `[p.val > root.val]`, interpreting the boolean as an int. There's a decent dupe somewhere around here.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm sure there is, it's hard to track down unfortunately, because people rarely know how to even ask about this. It's obvious once explained, but I definitely did a double-take the first time I saw it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[root.left, root.right]` is a `list` of 2 values.

`p.val > root.val` is a boolean used as an index: value can be 0 or 1.

So it's a way to avoid (explicitly) testing the value, just index the result according to `0` or `1` (but the test is still there)

While it may appear a to be a good idea, the efficiency of that construction in Python is dubious: it builds a list dynamically then it accesses it by index (with boundary checking), not to mention that it has to evaluate both `root.left` and `root.right` whatever the outcome may be (no short circuit).

I think you'd be better off with the following ternary expression:

```
root =  root.right if p.val > root.val else root.left
```

it's explicit, short-circuits, and doesn't create / accesses a temporary list.

Comment: This actually was the idiom before conditional expressions were introduced. You still see it sprinkled throughout Python code-bases.

Comment: I didn't know that. looks cool but it is not efficient. and it's insidious because most people don't see all the underlying operations. Could be slightly better if the 2-item array isn't dynamically allocated.

Comment: It's not so much the construction of a list that bothers me (really a trivial expense in Python, unless it's inside some deeply nested loop I wouldn't bother optimizing it). What really bothers me is that it doesn't short-circuit evaluation of `root.right` and `root.left`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga correct again. if you allow me, I'll add it in my answer. Another good reason not to use that.

Comment: By all means, add it!